If $\varphi : E \to F$ is a surjective bundle map at a point $p \in M$, then $\varphi$ is surjective in a neighborhood of $p$.
Let $E$ and $F$ be vector bundles over a smooth manifold $M$. I'm trying to figure out if the following claim holds:

If $\varphi : E \to F$ is a surjective bundle map at a point $p \in M$, then $\varphi$ is surjective in a neighborhood of $p$.

It might be that I'm not formulating this properly, but essentially I would like to say that if $p \in M$ and $\varphi_p : E_p \to F_p$ has full row rank, then for say a trivializing open neighborhood $U$ containing $p$, any $q \in U$ gives full row rank for $\varphi_q : E_q \to F_q$.
My idea was that this should follow from upper semicontinuity for $\operatorname{rk}$, but I cannot quite formulate this. We have that
$$
\limsup_{q \to p}\operatorname{rk}(\varphi_q) \le \operatorname{rk}(\varphi_p) = \dim(F_p),
$$
but this clearly says that $\operatorname{rk}(\varphi_q)$ can drop smaller than $\dim(F_p)$?

You have the semicontinuity upside-down.

Consider wlog a continuous map
$$\psi:U\to M_{m,n}(\Bbb R)=M_{m,m}(\Bbb R)\times M_{m,n-m}(\Bbb R),q\mapsto \pmatrix{A(q)&B(q)}$$ such that
$\det A(p)\ne0$.
By continuity, on a neighborhood of $p$, we still have $\det A(q)\ne0$ hence $\psi(q)$ is surjective.
